# Save JSON request as Item in dynamoDb

Tags: java, json, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a request of the following JSON format:

```
{
 "profile": {
             "created": 1505202655,
             "createdBy": "abc",
             "updated": 1505202655,
             "updatedBy": "xyz"
            },
"likesId": [
            "0010127916"
           ],
"icon": null,
"Attributes": {
               "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF",
               "logo": "images/Logos/P0010127916.jpg",
               "textColor": "#000000"
              },
"profileId": "PACYG0010916",
"restrictions": {
                 "clients": [
                             "Android",
                             "SmartTv"
                            ],
                 "UserTypes": [
                               "user1",
                               "user2"
                            ],
                 "periodEnd": 1512978849,
                 "periodStart": 1505202849
               },

}
```

I am trying to save the above JSON request Object in the dynamoDb table using putItem. However I am stuck in some issues which are as follows:

1. Can I store this whole JSON request as-is(without escaping double quotes) in the form of item in dynamodb table?
2. In case of likesId and Attributes I am storing them as a List and Map with the help of .withList and .withMap methods respectively, but in case of profile I have taken it as a POJO which has 4 states, how can I save this object with the putItem as I did not find any method for saving objects like this, as we have methods for string, numbers and other datatypes, how can I save my own object?

Any kind of guidance will be highly appreciated as I am new to dynamoDb and learning it by doing POC.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to save it quite easily with the `DocumentClient` class:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#put-property

```
var params = {
  TableName : 'Table',
  Item: item
};

var documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

documentClient.put(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  else console.log(data);
});
```

Where `item` is the object from your original question

Comment: what I am trying to ask is under var params, in Item attribute how can i provide my own created datatype i.e. my own class instead of predefined data types.

Comment: You can't really-- to an extent DynamoDB is schema-less. It really has no concept of class. You'd have to store it as a map

Comment: Ok, but storing it as a Map has one issue , in my profile attribute that map will have 2 types of values, both String and Long. So I was not preferring Map, as in Map<String, Object> Object is not identified by dynamoDb

Comment: "A map is similar to a JSON object. There are no restrictions on the data types that can be stored in a map element, and the elements in a map do not have to be of the same type." http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html

Comment: This is javaScript not Java as per the question